# Many horizontal images in two column latex format

Tags: tables, pgfplots, spacing, graphics, formatting

I have four to five images and i am trying to fit them horizontally in latex format :

What I have tried is :

```
\documentclass[sigchi]{acmart}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \providecommand\BibTeX{{%
    \normalfont B\kern-0.5em{\scshape i\kern-0.25em b}\kern-0.8em\TeX}}}


\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
\copyrightyear{2018}
\acmYear{2018}
\acmDOI{10.1145/1122445.1122456}

\acmConference[Woodstock '18]{Woodstock '18: ACM Symposium on Neural
  Gaze Detection}{June 03--05, 2018}{Woodstock, NY}
\acmBooktitle{Woodstock '18: ACM Symposium on Neural Gaze Detection,
  June 03--05, 2018, Woodstock, NY}
\acmPrice{15.00}
\acmISBN{978-1-4503-9999-9/18/06}



\begin{document}


\title{The Name of the Title is Hope}

\author{Ben Trovato}
\authornote{Both authors contributed equally to this research.}
\email{trovato@corporation.com}
\orcid{1234-5678-9012}
\author{G.K.M. Tobin}
\authornotemark[1]
\email{webmaster@marysville-ohio.com}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Institute for Clarity in Documentation}
  \streetaddress{P.O. Box 1212}
  \city{Dublin}
  \state{Ohio}
  \postcode{43017-6221}
}

\author{Lars Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{The Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld Group}
  \streetaddress{1 Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld Circle}
  \city{Hekla}
  \country{Iceland}}
\email{larst@affiliation.org}

\author{Valerie B\'eranger}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Inria Paris-Rocquencourt}
  \city{Rocquencourt}
  \country{France}
}

\author{Aparna Patel}
\affiliation{%
 \institution{Rajiv Gandhi University}
 \streetaddress{Rono-Hills}
 \city{Doimukh}
 \state{Arunachal Pradesh}
 \country{India}}

\author{Huifen Chan}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Tsinghua University}
  \streetaddress{30 Shuangqing Rd}
  \city{Haidian Qu}
  \state{Beijing Shi}
  \country{China}}

\author{Charles Palmer}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Palmer Research Laboratories}
  \streetaddress{8600 Datapoint Drive}
  \city{San Antonio}
  \state{Texas}
  \postcode{78229}}
\email{cpalmer@prl.com}

\author{John Smith}
\affiliation{\institution{The Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld Group}}
\email{jsmith@affiliation.org}

\author{Julius P. Kumquat}
\affiliation{\institution{The Kumquat Consortium}}
\email{jpkumquat@consortium.net}


\renewcommand{\shortauthors}{Trovato and Tobin, et al.}

%%
%% The abstract is a short summary of the work to be presented in the
%% article.
\begin{abstract}
  A clear and well-documented \LaTeX\ document is presented as an
  article formatted for publication by ACM in a conference proceedings
  or journal publication. Based on the ``acmart'' document class, this
  article presents and explains many of the common variations, as well
  as many of the formatting elements an author may use in the
  preparation of the documentation of their work.
\end{abstract}

%%
%% The code below is generated by the tool at http://dl.acm.org/ccs.cfm.
%% Please copy and paste the code instead of the example below.
%%
\begin{CCSXML}
<ccs2012>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10010520.10010553.10010562</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Computer systems organization~Embedded systems</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
 </concept>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10010520.10010575.10010755</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Computer systems organization~Redundancy</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>300</concept_significance>
 </concept>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10010520.10010553.10010554</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Computer systems organization~Robotics</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>100</concept_significance>
 </concept>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10003033.10003083.10003095</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Networks~Network reliability</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>100</concept_significance>
 </concept>
</ccs2012>
\end{CCSXML}

\ccsdesc[500]{Computer systems organization~Embedded systems}
\ccsdesc[300]{Computer systems organization~Redundancy}
\ccsdesc{Computer systems organization~Robotics}
\ccsdesc[100]{Networks~Network reliability}

%%
%% Keywords. The author(s) should pick words that accurately describe
%% the work being presented. Separate the keywords with commas.
\keywords{datasets, neural networks, gaze detection, text tagging}


%%
%% This command processes the author and affiliation and title
%% information and builds the first part of the formatted document.
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
ACM's consolidated article template, introduced in 2017, provides a
consistent \LaTeX\ style for use across ACM publications, and
incorporates accessibility and metadata-extraction functionality
necessary for future Digital Library endeavors. Numerous ACM and
SIG-specific \LaTeX\ templates have been examined, and their unique
features incorporated into this single new template.

If you are new to publishing with ACM, this document is a valuable
guide to the process of preparing your work for publication. If you
have published with ACM before, this document provides insight and
instruction into more recent changes to the article template.

The ``\verb|acmart|'' document class can be used to prepare articles
for any ACM publication --- conference or journal, and for any stage
of publication, from review to final ``camera-ready'' copy, to the
author's own version, with {\itshape very} few changes to the source.

\section{Template Overview}
As noted in the introduction, the ``\verb|acmart|'' document class can
be used to prepare many different kinds of documentation --- a
double-blind initial submission of a full-length technical paper, a
two-page SIGGRAPH Emerging Technologies abstract, a ``camera-ready''
journal article, a SIGCHI Extended Abstract, and more --- all by
selecting the appropriate {\itshape template style} and {\itshape
  template parameters}.



\section{Figures}

The ``\verb|figure|'' environment should be used for figures. One or
more images can be placed within a figure. If your figure contains
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{sample-franklin}
  \Description{The 1907 Franklin Model D roadster.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{sample-franklin}
  \Description{The 1907 Franklin Model D roadster.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{sample-franklin}
  \Description{The 1907 Franklin Model D roadster.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{sample-franklin}
  \Description{The 1907 Franklin Model D roadster.}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `sample-sigchi.tex'.
```

Which is coming something like this :

[image]

But I am looking for something like this :

[image]

Not 5 but at least 4 images horizontally.

[Here is my overleaf file](https://www.overleaf.com/read/qyddgzknbvfc)

Comment: 4 to 5 images with this size???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `subfigure` environment so that multiple images can be put together in same figure.
2. Use `figure*` environment to use the entire`textwidth`.
3. Adjust the figure width to ensure that all the subfigures fit in `textwidth`.

[image]

#### MWE

```
\documentclass[sigchi]{acmart}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{author 1}
\begin{abstract}
The abstract is a short summary of the work to be presented in the article.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\begin{figure*}[h]
  \centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \subcaption{The 1907 Franklin Model D roadster.}
\end{subfigure}
% <— this is important. There should be no empty line here. 
\begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \subcaption{The 1907 Franklin Model D roadster.}
\end{subfigure}
%
\begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
  \subcaption{The 1907 Franklin Model D roadster.}
\end{subfigure}
%
\begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \subcaption{The 1907 Franklin Model D roadster.}
\end{subfigure}

\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to increase or decrease the space between subfigures?

Comment: @AadityaUra reduce the image size by changing the `width` in `includegraphics`. You can write something like `width=0.7\textwidth` . Also use `\centering` inside `subfigure` if required.